# How to know if a point is singular regular

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem says to find a regular singular point of $$y''+4xy'+6y=0$$

I proceeded to calculate the limit of x approaching 0 of $$ x\frac {Q(x)}{P(x)} =0$$ and $$ x^2\frac {R(x)}{P(x)}=0 $$

So I found that x=0 is a regular singular point. However my textbook says that there is no regular singular point. Can someone explain to me why, since both limits are finite.

Thank you.

Comment: Regular singular points are what make the highest order derivative term vanish in the differential equation. That never happens, so there aren't any.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm not sure I follow

Comment: In the differential equation, when you plug in $x=0$, the $y'$ term disappears. There isn't an $x$ that will make that happen for $y''$